# Why can it not deserialize the json it just gave me in a GET a minute ago?

Tags: json

I did a GET a minute ago, and this json was the result:
'[{"initialTreatment":"1","finalTreatment":"24","totalTreatments":"24","uniqueWellId":"051234644200100619153738"}]'

I turned around and tried to PUT this same json back and it tells me it "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])", etc.etc.  It's not a list or array.  It's a simple string.  The object I am trying to deserialize to is exactly the same four properties, but I changed the first char to lowercase, although I have tried it with the original casing with the same result.  I don't know what else I can try!  I can't imagine a more simple request.  I must not be holding my top lip right.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The `[` and `]` make it an array or list. Sounds like you need to post a single item.

Answer (score -1):

oh, never mind.  Apparently, it only likes [] if it is actually an array.

Thanks everyone.